# Changing the marker-line-width of pin on cartodb

Tags: markers

I have problems changing the marker-line-width of my pin in cartodb.

I use the property marker-line-width but my marker line does not appear. Instead a bubble shows up when I increase the marker-line-width.

Here are my css code:

```
    /** category visualization */

    #untitled_table {
    marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
    marker-line-color: #000000;
    marker-line-width: 3;
    marker-line-opacity: 1;
    marker-placement: point;
    marker-type: ellipse;
    marker-width: 20;
    marker-allow-overlap: true;
    }

    #untitled_table[location="Embassy of Russian Federation"] {
    marker-file: url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/marker-18.svg);
    marker-fill: #41006D;
    marker-line-color: #000000;
    marker-line-width: 3;
    marker-line-opacity: 1;
    }
    #untitled_table[location="Embassy of the United States of America"] {
    marker-file: url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/marker-18.svg);
    marker-fill: #41006D;
    marker-line-color: #000000;
    marker-line-width: 3;
    marker-line-opacity: 1;
    }
    #untitled_table[location="European Union Delegation to Bangladesh"] {
    marker-file: url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/marker-18.svg);
    marker-fill: #41006D;
    marker-line-color: #000000;
    marker-line-width: 3;
    marker-line-opacity: 1;
    }
    #untitled_table[location="French Embassy"] {
    marker-file: url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/marker-18.svg);
    marker-fill: #41006D;
    marker-line-color: #000000;
    marker-line-width: 3;
    marker-line-opacity: 1;
    }
    #untitled_table[location="Holey Artisan Bakery"] {
    marker-file: url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/star-18.svg);
    marker-fill: #E31A1C;
    marker-line-color: #000000;
    marker-line-width: 3;
    marker-line-opacity: 1;
    }
    #untitled_table[location="Netherlands Embassy"] {
    marker-file: url(http://com.cartodb.users-assets.production.s3.amazonaws.com/maki-icons/marker-18.svg);
    marker-fill: #41006D;
    marker-line-color: #000000;
    marker-line-width: 3;
    marker-line-opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can someone help solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @ramiroaznar do you want to give this a try?

Comment: Still having this kind of problem? On my recent research about this the biggest issue was the way i generate the svg file. Let me know if you still having this kind of issue i'll give you more details about it.

Comment: No, I could not find a solution. In the end, I decided to change the marker and the base map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seng Yap,

The issue on my case is because the way i design my svg isn't right, share your svg file and a print of you isseu this will help to help you.

Here a sample of my cartoCSS code:

```
@color-marker-1:#4D4D4D;
@color-marker-2:#7ED321;
@color-marker-3:#FFCD00;
@color-marker-4:#FF7C00;
@color-marker-5:#D0021B;

#stylename [fid >= 1] [fid < 97.74193548387096] { 
  marker-file: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1756940/marker-days.svg"); 
  marker-fill: @color-marker-3;  
  marker-line-color:@color-marker-1;
  marker-line-width:1px;
  marker-line-opacity:1;
  marker-width: 8;
  marker-opacity: 0.9;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;   

 [zoom <=12]{
    marker-width:8;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have already change a base map with a good contrast, so I no longer need to change the marker line width.

Comment: No problem Seng, if any one have the same issue i hope my reply helps :D!